# s.split("\\d") java regex confusion

Tags: java, regex

```
String s="a1b2c3";    
String sarr[]=s.split(".*[\\d].*");//
for(String var:sarr)
     System.out.println("S: "+var);
     System.out.println(sarr.length);
```

Why is `sarr` is empty?

And if you replace `//` line with following:

```
String sarr[]=s.split("\\d");
```

Why does this give output `a b c`?

Comment: It helps to read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: Are you aware what `String#split` does?

Comment: Yes. but i m new to regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) state

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>
> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a **limit argument of zero**. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

The expression `.*[\d].*` matches the whole String, i.e `a1b2c3` is what to split around, so only two empty strings remain, which can be saved to the array, which this method does not do because of the limit `0`

```
String sarr[]=s.split(".*[\\d].*", -1);
```

shows those two empty strings

```
S: 
S: 
2
```

You could test the match by printing

```
System.out.println(s.matches(".*[\\d].*"));
```

the output is `true`.

The expression `\d` matches `1`, `2` and `3`, so splits are done around, which results in `[a, b, c]`